# Visual Studio C# intellisense : How to automatically insert parenthesis after method names?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

How to make Visual Studio to insert parenthesis automatically  after method names in C#?

Comment: is it too much to type a left parenthesis?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you've seen it happening somewhere, it's probably because they are using [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). Resharper does that by default.

Answer (score 0):

i know its very old but in case of new user looking for a solution other than `Resharper`
 just use [Macro](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MacrosforVisualStudio) to record `();` this. 
i just added `Shift + |` and it makes life easier.